# Chapter and numbering overlapping in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I've a problem in my table of contents. Some overlap of the numbering of chapter and the corresponding title. Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\title{My title}


\titleformat{\section}
{\color{red}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{red}\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{red}\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\color{red}\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}    

\maketitle
\tableofcontents



\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

and here is the (bad) result:

[image: bad table of contents]

Answer (score 4):

A disclaimer in the `amsart` documentation warns you that the document class is not compatible with all available packages. In your case, it appears that it is is incompatible with `titlesec` (this is because `amsart.cls` defines its own sectioning commands, table of contents etc.). The authors probably didn't intend you to modify the table of contents style.

Beyond trying to hack the `amsart.cls` file, which I do not recommend (if you are publishing with AMS you should use their class as is), your options are to use a more conventional document class compatible with `titlesec`, such as `article`.

As an aside, I did manage to achieve your intended outcome *with* the `amsart` document class by commenting `\usepackage{titlesec}`, attempting to compile (fail), un-commenting the same line and then compiling (success). This is not a sensible workaround as you will likely encounter other incompatibilities down the line:

[image: output]